# Replace text to number php

Tags: replace, str-replace

I need to replace a simple text with comma inside to number.

```
CSV File: 

Test1
Test1, Test2
Test1, Test2, Test3
```

php code

```
$text = "Test1";
$text1 = "Test1, Test2";
$text1 = "Test1, Test2, Test3";

$search = array('$text','$text1','$text2');
$replace = array('10','11','12');
$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $file);
echo "$result";
```

the result is: "10","10, 11","10, 11, 12"

but I want to get "10","11","12".

This is the final script but on one of this im getting "10, 12"

```
$text1 = "Test1";
$text2 = "Test2";
$text3 = "Test3";
$text4 = "Test1, Test2, Test3";
$text5 = "Test1, Test2";
$text6 = "Test1, Test3";
$text7 = "Test2, Test3";
$text8 = "Blank";
array($text8,$text7,$text6,$text5,$text4,$text3,$text2,$text1);
array('10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to have these string literals:

```
$search = array('$text','$text1','$text2');
```

Try

```
$search = array($text,$text1,$text2);
```

When you use single-quotes, variables are not parsed, so

```
$text1 = 'Hello';
$text2 = '$text1';
echo $text2; // $text1
```

Vs

```
$text1 = 'Hello';
$text2 = $text1;
echo $text2; // Hello
```

The result from:

```
Test1
Test1, Test2
Test1, Test2, Test3
```

Would be that each instance of Test1 is replaced with 10, and so on - so:

```
10
10, 11
10, 11, 12
```

*Update*

I see what you are trying to do. When you pass arrays into `str_replace` it processes them in order - so by the time it looks for `Test1, Test2` you have already replaced `Test1` with 10. Reverse the order to do what you want...

```
$text = "Test1";
$text1 = "Test1, Test2";
$text2 = "Test1, Test2, Test3";

$search = array($text2,$text1,$text); // reversed
$replace = array('12', '11', '10');// reversed
$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $file);
echo $result;
```

Comment: is the same, i tried with '' and without and also with "" Thanks

Comment: yes i understand, but how can i replace the Test1, Test2 to 11 ?

Comment: Are you saying you want `Test1, Test2` to result in `11` and `Test1, Test2, Test3` to result in `12`? I have added an update to do that...

Comment: maybe can be used preg_replace ?

Comment: yes, i want Test1, Test2 to be 11 and Test1, Test2, Test3 to 12

Comment: I have updated the result with your solution, on one of combination is getting 2 numbers inside like "10, 11"

Comment: Thanks Steve, just i arranged the order on conversion reversed and work like charm. Thanks